# Why do hyphens in module names generate syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm using python 2.6 and get the following when importing a module:

```
  File "./test-nmea-uploader.py", line 11
    import nmea-uploader as sut
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is that so? The python style guide seems to hold no mention about using hyphens in names, although it suggest the use of underscores.

Alan

Comment: A class/variable name cannot contain hyphens.

Comment: I think it's because the interpreter can't distinguish between the name `a-b` and the operation `a [MINUS] b` -- how will it know whether you meant the variable named `a-b` or variable `a` minus variable `b`?

Comment: You can do: `sut = __import__('nmea-uploader')` thought...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers, any identifier must **start** with a lowercase/uppercase letter or an underscore and **contain** lowercase/uppercase letters, numbers or an underscore.

Package names are identifiers, so they are bound to the same rules.

In addition, `nmea-uploader` might also mean the subtraction of `uploader` from `nmea`.
Since you can import a package anywhere in a python file, if you have defined the variables `nmea` and `uploader` in advance, the interpreter would get confused if a hyphen was allowed for identifier names.

Comment: must start with a letter OR an underscore

Answer (score 8):

Identifiers cannot contain hyphens. This is not a question of style, but a part of the language syntax, see http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following lexical definitions:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

Answer (score 6):

The character `-` is an operator in python so you can't use it in an identifier.

See [Lexical analysis — Python v2.7.2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: Nice answer.  To expand on this, if `a-b` were an identifier then it couldn't be a subtraction.  When reading a `.py` file, `python` first breaks the file into tokens, and this is done in a [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) manner so a dash is a full token whether it follows the keyword `import` or as part of an expression.

Answer (score 3):

> The python style guide seems to hold no mention about using hyphens in names

Because the python **style guide** is totally irrelevant to determining what is an **error** in your code or not.

The style guide suggests what you **should** use. To determine what you **may** use, consult the language grammar, or other such documentation.